# Enumerize for a hash in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enumerize

I'm using gem enumerize in my project. For now I have this:

```
class MyAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

  enumerize :country, in: [:country1, :country2, :country3], default: :country2

end
```

Now I want to convert `state` to be `enumerize`. Obviously, each country has its own states. How can I do something like this:

```
class MyAddress < ActiveRecord::Base

  enumerize :country, in: [:country1, :country2, :country3], default: :country2
  enumerize :state, in: [{ country1: [:state11, :state12, :state13], country2: [:state21, :state22, :state23], country3: [:state31, :state32, :state33]} ]

end
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Don't you have to say `extend Enumerize` in your class definition?

Comment: @JohnC, it's a model, updated.

Answer (score 2):

The gem documentation doesn't indicate this sort of thing is possible. And it makes sense that it wouldn't. An enumeration is simply a mapping between a key (or name) and a value (an integer). In your example you're essentially looking to map the country (key) to an array of non-numeric values. So that doesn't make sense.

I would suggest you organize your states by country with code comments and just let the enumeration be simple.

```
enumerize :state,
          in: [
            # Country 1
            :state11, :state12, :state13,
            # Country 2
            :state21, :state22, :state23
          ]
```

Enumerations aren't ever really "easy" to remember what the key is for a given value stored. So you'll just have to come up with a way to make it a bit simpler to look up (as I've attempted to do above).

Comment: and how would dynamically determine which country does a state belong to?

Comment: You could probably use ranges like `if (state11..state13).cover?(state) then country1`. This could be in a method like `get_country_from(state)` or whatever.